# How come padding is not calculated into the width for submit buttons?

Tags: html, css

First of all, I think it is absolutely ridiculous that padding is considered part of the width of a DOM element.

However, I eventually gritted my teeth and accepted this fact... only to find out that for submit buttons the paddings are NOT calculated as part of the width.

http://jsfiddle.net/CPRyb/2/

How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you just misspoke, but the padding is not considered part of the width by default. That is to say, if an element has a width of 100px, padding of 10px, and border of 5px, then it will be rendered over 100+(10*2)+(5*2)=130px. However, the element will only contain 100px of space, which is the amount set in `width`.

That being said, you can change the default behavior with the `box-sizing` property. Just set it to `border-box` to subtract the padding (and border) from the box's width, or `content-box` to render the padding outside of the specified width. Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qWEgF/).

For increased compatibility you should also include the vendor prefixes. So,

```
input[type=button] {
  -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
  box-sizing:content-box;
}
```

Comment: Great, the newest gecko rendering engine has a bug for box-sizing ><. 

Also I meant that putting paddings to an element makes the element wider, but it is not considered part of the width property.

edit: using the prefix -moz works for gecko. Ok good enough for now.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Also, I skimmed through the bug report, and it looks like the bug is only that it requires the -moz- prefix. So you should be set.

Answer (score 1):

Styling input tag is a nightmare, they behaves weirdly across browsers, so there is no easy solution if you try this way.

One workaround is to wrap inputs in a div tag and stylize it.
My cross-browser solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/hRCNS/1/

html:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="text">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div class="button">
    <input type="submit" />
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div.main
{
     width: 300px;   
     text-align: center;
}
input
{
    width: 100%;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background: transparent;
}
.text {
    border:solid 1px #bbb;
    padding: 10px;
}

.button {
    margin:1px;
    border:solid 1px #bbb;
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.button input {
    padding:4px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.button:hover {
    background:#ccc;
}
.button:active {
    background:#999;   
}
```

doing this way you also workaround that width calculation crap and can customize the looks nicely. ;)

Comment: Also, please dont use box-sizing, it is not widely supported currently.

Comment: it's been supported since Chrome 1.0, Firefox 1.0, Safari 3.0, Opera 7.0, and IE8. At some point you're going to have to give up on the dinosaurs.

Comment: I am using Firefox 9.0 and it does not support box-sizing without the -moz- prefix. Properties with vendor prefix may change in a future, I know it is very unlikely in this case, but I don't like to base my layout in something not trustful.

Comment: Right, I was including support for vendor-prefixed versions. As for changing support, it doesn't seem to me that it could change in a way that would be problematic. AFAIK later versions of firefox would only change their treatment of `-moz-box-sizing` to fix a bug, so if it works bug-free now then there's nothing to worry about. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: Yeah, I may start using box-sizing when IE7 is dead. I agree with Razor that the default box model is crap. But, for now, I will just feed that dinossaur.

Comment: Heh, fair enough. I guess it just depends on your target audience - if you're dealing with a less technological crowd, or a particularly large and important website, then it's probably a good idea to set the cutoff a bit further back. (Although Google, progressive as always, doesn't officially support IE7 in Google Apps any more)

Answer (score 0):

change css

```
.button {
display: block;
padding: 10px;
}
```

and don't use ending tag for input